Geyser subscribe to token transfers
I want to be able to subscribe to account updates only of token accounts of a certain mint. I currently have this but getting all sorts of transfers not just of my token
const tokenMint = new PublicKey("Eb8bEo6fVNhW5LsgYdqkz1R62a4LzRKiKhGMxedDpump")
const req: SubscribeRequest = {
 accounts: {
    [tokenMint.toBase58()]: {
       filters: [{ memcmp: { offset: "0", base58: tokenMint.toBase58() }, datasize: "165" }],
       account: [],
       owner: [],
    },
 },
 slots: {},
 transactions: {},
 transactionsStatus: {},
 entry: {},
 blocks: {},
 blocksMeta: {},
 accountsDataSlice: [],
 ping: undefined,
 commitment: CommitmentLevel.CONFIRMED,
};


I got it just needed to provide the datasize in an object. Typescript didn't throw up any errors for leaving it outside the object but it wasn't applying the filter
const tokenMint = new PublicKey("7SQ1bPmUhAAKbnyrFsbVp13De1qMvg7kjAWMXZLqpump")
const req: SubscribeRequest = {
  accounts: {
    [tokenMint.toBase58()]: {
        filters: [{ memcmp: { offset: "0", base58: tokenMint.toBase58() } }, { datasize: "165" }],
        account: [],
        owner: [],
    },
  },
  slots: {},
  transactions: {},
  transactionsStatus: {},
  entry: {},
  blocks: {},
  blocksMeta: {},
  accountsDataSlice: [],
  ping: undefined,
  commitment: CommitmentLevel.PROCESSED,
};

